# Add line of text at line after specific pattern

Tags: powershell

As part of a small personal project I am trying to learn a bit of Powershell scripting.

The current problem I am trying to solve is, given a folder with hundreds of ASCII text files in it, for each of the files:

- find the lines where a specific text is in a `.txt` file (there might be none, there might be several)
- if there are none, add new text on line 3 (of the resulting file)
- if there is one or multiple ones, add new text as a new line just before the first hit

I managed to find out how to locate the lines

```
gci -literalpath "C:\path" -rec -filter *.txt | % {
$line = Select-String -literalpath $_.fullname -pattern "foo_bar" | select LineNumber
}
```

and I know how to add a line at a specific line number (in this case, the third line of the resulting file)

```
gci -literalpath "C:\path" -rec -filter *.txt | % {
$file = get-Content -literalpath $_.fullname
set-content -literalpath $_.fullname -value ($file[0..1] + "newline" + $file[2..($file.Length-1)])
}
```

The problem I have is that I seem to be unable to work with `$line`, I was expecting an `int` (since `LineNumber` is) but if I type `$line.GetType()` I get `PSCustomObject` as answer and I can't find a way to extract the integer value from it, and it is there, if I print `$line` I get an output similar to

```
LineNumber
-------------
4
5
10
```

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you try `[Int]$line = Select-String ..` or `$line.LineNumber`?

Comment: @DarkLite1 I will as soon as I get a hold of my usual machine, I can't run the script on this one (O_o, both Win7). Thanks

Comment: `| Select -ExpandProperty LineNumber` will return the value of `LineNumber`, instead of a `PSCustomObject` with a `LineNumber` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Linenumber like this:

```
$line.LineNumber
```

Or you can do this:

```
gci -literalpath "C:\path" -rec -filter *.txt | % {
$line = Select-String -literalpath $_.fullname -pattern "foo_bar" | select -ExpandProperty LineNumber
}
```

in this case you will have a integer variable. Be aware though that if you have multiple matches it will be an Array and not an Integer.

For your future endeavours the cmdlet `Get-Member` might help you exploring PSObjects.

Example usage: `$line | get-member`

Comment: Or no matches is possible as well.

Comment: @Matt is obviously right, in this case `$line` will be `$null`

Comment: Pretty sure as well that `select LineNumber -ExpandProperty LineNumber` is redundant and `select -ExpandProperty LineNumber` works just as well

Comment: @matt feel free to correct my answers when you find stuff like that